# Convert PKCS1 string to Java PrivateKey

Tags: java, oauth, jwt, pkcs#1

I have a PKCS1 String of the form:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIC...
.
..
...
....S5m5x9yZY=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How can I convert this string (in a file) to a `java.security.PrivateKey` object ?